# Best IP configuration in a small network with one Server and 21 clients

Tags: internet, lan

I have a single server and 21 clients which I want to connect via ethernet(LAN) using a D-Link 24 port switch.  I also have a Broadband internet connection which I want to be accessable for the Server and the clients.

My question is: What would be the best IP configuration for the server and clients (including Subnet Mask, Default Gateway and Preferred DNS Server Address)?

Comment: What does your research show?  There are several dozen choices and they are all correct. What your intranet ip address, subnet mask, and dns server is, is left up to you

Comment: yes but for server and client it same or different i don't know

Comment: While it's possible to assigned the same ip address to multiple devices, doing so wouldn't make sense, because that would cause a conflict.  You should research the side effect of doing that.

Comment: if my server IP address Is 192.168.1.1 Subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 Default Gateway is 192.168.1.1 Preferred DNS Server is 192.168.1.1 what should be clients

Comment: If you're not able to complete even this basic setup, I would advise you to get a professional to set things up for you.

Comment: assuming you have a broadband router and a server (that aren't the same piece of hardware) your server IP probably shouldn't be the same as the default gateway. The default gateway would usually be the address of your router, the server IP should be different. Everything on the network should have the same subnet mask, gateway and preferred dns. Addresses in your example could range from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254, though no two devices should have the same IP address.

Comment: my router address is 192.168.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the IP address/mask, gateway and DNS servers are automatically provisioned by DHCP from your broadband router. If you are assigning addresses manually, you need to make sure all computers are on the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork), ideally using a range reserved for [private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses). Your broadband router will have to be on the same subnet, you may prefer to set the PCs to use the default subnet your router uses, rather than reconfiguring your router.

For all devices on the same network, the default gateway is typically the address of the router, and preferred DNS servers set either to the address of your router, or your ISPs DNS servers or any public dns of your choice such as [Google DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) or [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/) (or any combination, multiple servers can be assigned for redundancy)

The subnet mask is used in conjunction with the IP address to determine how devices communicate with each other. On a small network you usually want all devices to be on the same subnet. In this case all devices will have the same subnet mask, the address assigned to each device needs to be unique, but within the subnet as [defined by the subnet mask](https://youtu.be/Deq9Dq-Kc-k).

Once your server and clients are configured on the network you should be able to [test pinging](http://www.wikihow.com/Ping-an-IP-Address) the address of the server from the clients (you may have to the firewall on the device you are trying to ping, or temporarily disable it). You can also use the ping tool as a step in troubleshooting connectivity problems to the gateway, or to Internet servers.

`ipconfig` is a useful tool in windows to inspect the network settings windows is using, either manually set or set automatically via DHCP.

Best practice on a small network is either set the servers address manually (to an address inside the subnet, but is outside of the range assigned by your routers DHCP, you'll have to log in to your router to determine the range it assigns), or to configure your router to keep the address assigned to that server static (guarantees the server is always assigned the same address)

Comment: The author is using a switch, which means, it's very unlikely to have DHCP functionality built into it.

Comment: Agreed, a switch would not serve DHCP, it depends more on what type of Internet service he has and what hardware (router/modem etc) he uses. A typical broadband router used in most parts of the world runs a DHCP server, if that router is plugged in to the switch, the clients would be served addresses by the router. Your point is valid Ramhound, I should have first asked bharat what type of Internet service he has, and what hardware he uses, or was provided by his ISP to connect.

Comment: i have an broadband internet connection and router

Comment: If its truly a router (terminology isn't always clear) I assume if you plug a computer in to that router, it has Internet access without having to manually configure an IP address etc? if so you should be able to plug the switch into the router, then the computer in to the switch and still be able to access the Internet. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding your situation or requirements.

Comment: yes but i also want to access file from server on client how can configure it

Comment: What happens if you plug both the server and a client into the switch (with the switch plugged in to the router)? do they both get an address (might be able to check with `ipconfig`) and both access the Internet? If not can you provide the make & model of the router?

Comment: yes both access the internet

Comment: Good news. Can you access the server from the client? Without more detail (operating system of server and clients, what type of server, or services does the server maintain, file shares, or specific software) I can't guide you through testing or troubleshooting that.

Comment: can't able to access server from client operating system of server and client is windows 7 server type  specific software

Comment: can you describe what the server should do? Is it for clients to store files? If its hosting specific software for the clients to access, what software is it? What operating system is the server running? If both server and client are connected to the switch you could be able to ping the server from the client eg run `ping 192.168.1.2` from a cmd prompt (make sure you use the correct address from the server, check `ipconfig` on the server). you should see replies, if not try turning off any firewalls on the server temporarily.

Comment: server hosting specific software(eLearning Content) for the clients to access software, server running on windows7 64 bit, both the server and client connected to the switch, also broadband router connected to switch.  What would be the best IP configuration for the server and clients (including IP address, Subnet Mask, Default Gateway and Preferred DNS Server Address)? Router address is 192.168.0.1

Comment: Use the same subnet mask, gateway and dns thats automatically assigned. See the last paragraph of my answer for guidance on choosing the server IP. assuming the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 then anything from 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3 etc up to 192.168.0.254 should work. Make sure you can ping the server from clients (may need to disable firewall). Seek guidance on configuring the eLearning software from the vendor or supplier of that software.

Answer (score -1):

The one thing I don't see being mentioned is that you really don't want your broadband router to be the DHCP Server. On the workstations the DNS must be the Windows Server or nothing much will work. The Windows Server should be the DHCP and DNS. You want to shut off the DHCP Server on the router. Most routers of the class you are talking have a default IP address. I would let it dictate your subnet. The reason being... routers often reset themselves to factor defaults. If you leave the router at its factor default IP then even it it resets itseld the IP address will remain the same (you will have to re-disable the DHCP Server on it after a factory reset though). So... lets assume the default IP address on the router is 192.168.1.1.....

I would static IP the server at 192.168.1.2 and then set up your DHCP Server on the server with the following:

Pass out IP Range 192.168.1.100 thru 192.168.1.200 (this will leave room for more things you want to static IP before and after that range)

The gateway would be 192.168.1.1 (the router)

The DNS Server (and WINS Server if you choose to use it) would be 192.168.1.2 (the server)

Local Domain (your domain)

That has the DHCP set you. Then on the DNS all you need to do is use forwarders, preferably the two provided by your ISP.

That's basically it. Windows network 101. If you hit a snag just yell and I'll give you more detail.